# Enum NullPointerException

Tags: java, enums, nullpointerexception

Could anyone explain why

```
public class Testabut{
    enum ThreeColors{RED, BLUE, green;
        public void woowoo(){
        System.out.println("woo");}
    }
     ThreeColors color;



    class Innerclass{
        Innerclass(){
             color.woowoo();
        }
    }
```

generates a null pointer exception at the invocation of woowoo() ?
The instance of color should be reachable, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `color` is not initialized and it's default value is `null`.
Initialize it like

```
ThreeColors color = ThreeColors.RED;  //Or any other value
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `color` variable is null. You have to initialize it to use it.

Answer (score 2):

All instance variables are initialized with a value. If you do not provide a value, the variable will be assigned the *default* value for the type. For non-primitive types, the default value is `null`.

Currently, your code is equivalent to:

```
ThreeColors color = null;
```

So when you use it, of course you get a NPE. Instead, try something like this:

```
ThreeColors color = ThreeColors.RED;
```

Answer (score 1):

> The instance of color should be reachable, no?

There is no instance, `color` is `null` by default, because it is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `color`. Try `color = ThreeColors.RED;` or `color = ThreeColors.BLUE;` or `color = ThreeColors.green;`!

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize `color` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this (or whichever colour you like) :

```
ThreeColors color = ThreeColors.RED;
```